# Conocer lo clickeado por el usuario metodo confirm

Tags: javascript, c#

Tengo la siguiente instruccion con la cual mis pretenciones son indicarle a un usuario si quiere o o no imprimir un informe.

en caso de que sea `True` imprima y en caso de que sea `false` solo redirige

```
 Response.Write("<script lengue>confirm('¿Desea Imprimir Este informe?')</script>");
```

mi duda es como le puedo conocer la opcion que el usuario haya realizado

Mi proyecto esta en c#, pero empleo algunos eventos de JS

`Response.Write("<script lengue>var resultado = confirm('¿Desea Imprimir Este informe?')</script>");`

si lo incorporó de esa manera, como accedo a la variable resultado desde fuera el script?

Comment: `var data = confirm("Desea Imprimir Este informe?")` aquí en la variable `data` se guarda `true` si da click en Aceptar o `false` si da click en "Cancelar" no se si es lo que pretendes o estés buscando.

Comment: `Response.Write("<script lengue>var resultado = confirm('¿Desea Imprimir Este informe?')</script>");`  si lo incorporo de esta manera, como accedo a resultado desde fuera el script?

Comment: Eso ya sería una pregunta de c#, y bueno no por ser sangrón pero como nada más viene el tag de javascript y solo preguntas cómo acceder al dato, más no cómo acceder a el desde ya sea javascript o c# ahí si habría que esperar a que alguien de c# pueda proporcionar la respuesta

Comment: crea una peticion ajax y una vex que la responda haces un dopostback, pero trata de no mezclar el codigo de esa forma

Comment: hola @JackNavaRow gracias por responder, ya he logrado resolverlo. Mi conocimiento en ajax es null, pero me gustaria ver como seria esta solucion que comentas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He logrado hacer lo que requeria empleando la siguiente tecnica

```
Response.Write("<script language=javascript>");
Response.Write("if(confirm('¿Desea Imprimir Este informe?')){window.location.href='../Visor/ConstruirReporte.aspx?Reporte=CRE9&id=" + TextBoxRecibo.Text + "'}");
Response.Write("</script>");
```

no se si sea la mas factible u idonea, pero lo he logrado hacer de esa forma

Answer (score 4):

La función [`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) devuelve un valor `true` (OK) o `false` (Cancelar)

```js
var resultado = confirm('¿Sí o No?');

console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: En C# como lo podria hacer?

Comment: Hasta aquí tienes el valor en el lado cliente (navegador del usuario), si quieres usar ese valor en C# tienes que enviarlo al servidor.  ¿que necesitas que ocurra cuando el usuario haga clic en OK?

Comment: En mi caso, lo que requiero es que si el usuario presiona si, se imprima un informe, en caso que sea contrario solo lo muestre

Comment: ¿Dónde tiene que imprimirse el informe, en la computadora donde está abierto el navegador o en el servidor? Sí es el navegador estás obligado a hacerlo en JS.

Comment: el informe esta del lado del servidor, es un informe que se construye en tiempo de ejecución y se muestra en el navegador. Ya he construido un metodo del lado del servidor que imprime el informe directamente. Ahora lo que requiere es preguntarle al usuario si lo quiere imprimir o no

Comment: Entonces agrega en tu script la decisión (`if`) si llamar o no a la función del servidor, como sea que la llames.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85476/discussion-between-andrex-11-and-diego-torres).

Answer (score 1):

Te muestro un ejemplo con solo JavaScript , ejecuto jQuery para buscar el path de descarga, una vez obtenido el path ejecuto el window.location.href y descargamos el archivo

```js
if (confirm('¿Desea Imprimir Este informe?')){
  $.ajax({
  
   url : 'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random',
   type : 'GET',
   dataType:'json',
   success : function(data) {
    console.log("retornara el path para descargar");
    window.location.href ="https://legacy.gitbook.com/download/pdf/book/danielmoralesp/javascript-avanzado-en-espanol"
  
   },
   error : function(request,error)
   {
    alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
   }
  
  
  })
 }else{
     window.location.href ="https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/28035/jacknavarow"
  }
```

```html
Este ejemplo usa jQuery
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```